# .htaccess rule ignored for no obvious reason

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My web project's directory structure looks like this:

```
webroot/
├── web/
│   ├── backend/
│   │   ├── endpoint/
│   │   │   └── endpoint.php
│   │   └── ...
│   └── frontend/
│       ├── app/
│       │   └── ...
│       ├── assets/
│       │   └── ...
│       ├── index.html
│       └── app.js
└── .htaccess
```

As you can see, my frontend (AngularJS) resides in `/web/frontend`. To be a able to access the app using a simpler canonical URL I created the following `.htaccess` file that basically maps `www.example.com/` to `www.example.com/web/frontend/`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# 1: css/js/img files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ web/frontend/assets/$1 [QSA,L]

# 2: AngularJS app/files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^app/(.*)$ public/frontend/app/$1 [QSA,L]

# 3: Backend/API -- this rule seems to be ignored
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^endpoint/(.*)$ web/backend/endpoint/$1 [QSA,L]

# 4: redirect to canonical URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} public/frontend/
RewriteRule ^web/frontend/(.*) http://<host>/$1 [R=301,L]

# 5: everything else to be routed by AngularJS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web/frontend/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/frontend/#/$1 [L]
```

This works fine for the frontend part which means that the app - including all assets - is loaded properly by the browser.

The thing I'm struggling with is basically the backend access. In my understanding I should be able to retrieve `/web/backend/endpoint/endpoint.php?foo=bar` through `/endpoint/endpoint.php?foo=bar` since rule #3 tells Apache to do so.

Instead, everytime I go to `/endpoint/endpoint.php?foo=bar`, the server returns the frontend's `index.html` (which means that rule #5 is executed).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

There is some syntax error in this Rule, please check it out. If you comment this, then the redirection to endpoint works as expected.

```
# 5: everything else to be routed by AngularJS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web/frontend/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/frontend/#/$1 [L]
```

So you need to fix rule # 5 with proper syntax, otherwise your php files won't get mapped and it won't allow php files to get executed because of the error in .htaccess file.